# Half border for html table

Tags: html, css, angularjs, html-table, border

I have a table in my web page that I want to only have half borders.

Example:

The table that I have:

```
A | B | C
  |   |
A | B | C
  |   |
A | B | C
```

Note:

```
td { padding-bottom: 5%; }
td#B { border-left: 1px solid black; border-right: 1px solid black}
/* Assuming alphabets A , B and C are ids of each td */
```

The table that I want:

```
A | B | C

A | B | C

A | B | C
```

How can I achieve this?

I am using angularjs' `ng-repeat` to display the data from a json database for the table.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: use margin instead of padding

Comment: instead padding, try add transparent borders, if that doesn't work, set a snippet or HTML/CSS code in your question to show what you did and where you failed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small table property can do the trick . Use this css in your table css:

```
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0 2em;
}
```

> Working snippet:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0 2em;
}

td {
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

tr td:last-child {
  border-right: 0px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>




</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either use an extra border on `tr` or `border-spacing` .

The difference can be seen while a border or background is applied to table :

```css
table {
/* demo purpose mainly */
  float:left;
  margin:1em;
  background:lightgray;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px green;;
}
.bdtr {  
border-collapse:collapse;
}
td {padding:0 1em;}
td + td {
  border-left:1px solid;
}
.bdtr tr + tr{
  border-top:1em lightgray solid; /* use background-color */
}
 
.bdtd {
  border-spacing:0 1em;
  margin:0 1em;
}
```

```html
<table class="bdtr">
<caption>border on tr</caption>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="bdtd">
<caption> border-spacing</caption>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Also, you can use transparent border and shadow to allow a non plain background on table or behind it :

```css
.bdtr {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 0 1em;
}

.bdtr.bis {
  background: linear-gradient(60deg, gray, yellow, purple, pink, lime);
}

.bdtr.bis tr+tr {
  border-top: 1em transparent solid;
}

.bdtr.bis tr td+td {
  border: none;/* reset from previous demo */
  box-shadow: inset 2px 0;
}
```

```html
<table class="bdtr bis">
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of applying the style to the `td` try to apply it to the `tr` 
And remove the padding on the `td`

```
tr {
  margin: 10px 0;
  display: block;
}
```